# Compling Projects in Visual Studio 2003 (When windows is running in safe mode)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, project, visual-studio-2003, rebuild

We have a asp.net application which used Crystal Reports 9. I do not know how the development system was configured but I used to open the project in Visual Studio 2003, make changes and upload the dll (and sometimes the aspx files ) to the production server.

Now that system is giving me a blue screen. It's not completely gone but I am able to boot the computer in Safe-mode. What my issue is that Visual Studio 2003 is unable to open the Project - because IIS (webserver) is not available. I tried the command line building (devenv build ) but it doesn't help - Is there a way to build/rebuild the project when the OS is in safe mode??

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to manually start IIS in Safe Mode, through the Services application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself set up with another build environment that doesn't require Safe Mode as soon as possible and transfer any source off of the old machine.

Safe Mode is intended to be a stop-gap for diagnostics / fixing up your PC, rather than a variation on Windows proper.  You're better off trying to roll back your Windows to an earlier state with System Restore so you can get back into normal Windows.